# Multi Model Wizard Form Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wizard, polymorphic-associations, rails-models

I've been banging my head on this problem for a while now, But can't seem to find a reasonable answer. I'll describe my problem and my setup. Hopefully I can get some ideas!

**The Problem**

Im trying to create a "wizard" form where the user can click through the various steps in order to reach the end. It traverses nested models and non nested models. I have been able to get it working with all the nested models, but im having trouble with a polymorphic association. So here is my setup

**Event**
 
has many :topics
 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :topics

**Topic**
 
has_many :resource_links

**Speaker**
 
has_many :resource_links, :as => :resource

I can create multiple topics on the create event form using "fields_for", but I want to be able to create speakers for each topic at the same time. But I can't use a "fields for", because it's not a direct association.

I am just sticking everything on the same form and separating it using javascript, so it's all hitting the event controller.

(Please excuse me if im not being clear, i've been looking at this so long im getting muddled)

Please let me know if you need more information! I appreciate all suggestions!